# How can I get rid of all duplicate watches in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

I have [**created a simple TODO app**](http://jsbin.com/yuyefajuyi/1/edit?html,js,output) with AngularJS.

[image]

So I have here a list of TODOs.  I can delete , set as completed , and add new ones.

I can also edit the title via double clicking the bold text. And now - a text input will appear instead:

[image]

Basically , each row ( under the ng-repeat) has an invisible input which I play with its visibilkity :

```
<li ng-repeat="todo in vm.todos....."  ...>

    <div ng-hide="vm.isTheEdited(todo)"> //this is "read" mode
         ....show checkbox + Label + Delete button
    </div>

    <input  ... show="vm.isTheEdited(todo)"....  /> // this is the "edit" mode

  </li>
```

All OK

But I saw [this code which counts](https://gist.github.com/kentcdodds/31c90402750572107922) watchers in an App .

So I enhanced it to show unique items and in a string way.

*(All I did was adding)* :

```
Array.prototype.unique = function(a){
    return function(){ return this.filter(a) }
}(function(a,b,c){ return c.indexOf(a,b+1) < 0 })

console.log(getWatchers().unique().length);
console.log(getWatchers().unique().map(function (a){return a.exp;}));
)*
```

**This is not important.**

The important thing is that it has many **duplicates** watchers !!!

Look at the results :

[image]

**Question**
why do I have so many duplicates entries and how can I reduce the number of the watchers? (and eliminate dups)

All I did was to use ng-show and hide via some value of function.

Comment: Did u try bind once? http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/removing-the-unneeded-watches/  We did it in our app and decreased our watchers by like 30%

Comment: @kcbeard Yes I have with the new way of `::...`. But that  will only do with unneeded-rebind information. like a title or so. I tried it with the global counters below , and they **stopped** updated when I changed the totos.

Comment: What about using ng-if instead of ng-show? So the element is rendered only when isTheEdited returns true. At this point it is rendering every time regardless of whether it is shown. I know that doesn't answer the question though.

Comment: That is a watch on every itteration of ng-show isnt it?

Comment: I believe so , if you meant ngrepeat ...

Comment: Yes, its a watch set for each repeat item. I belive ng-if will not render the element therefore not create the watchers

Comment: Cause i belive the function isTheEdited will run on every digest cycle, because it uses ng-show defined as a function. If I am remembering correctly

Comment: ng-switch removed DOM elements as well

Comment: @kcbeard Hi. Sorry about the delayed reply. ( just woke up). Your approach reduced from 49 watchers to  44 ( as you can see [**here**](http://jsbin.com/yipojoxeji/1/edit?html,js,output) : just open the console and wait 5 sec). Still I see many `vm.isTheEdited(todo)`. Why is that ?

Comment: Have you taken a look at Batarang? If you are having issues with performance Batarang can help you to see more of what is going on inside the watch tree.  https://youtu.be/q-7mhcHXSfM

Comment: take a look into your filter as well. Since it is on the repeat itself.

Comment: User Is right, ng-if creates a watcher but doesn't create a watcher on directives used within the element it was supposed to render. If I am understanding correctly, ng-show should only really be used when you expect a user to toggle visibility frequently.

Comment: :: bindonce your label title decreases a little more, not much but a little

Comment: @kcbeard  i did try to do it but then after updating the ng-model input - the label didnt update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact I don't think there isn't any duplicate: both ngShow an ngHide create a watcher and you can't do anything to avoid that using native directives: you should expect at least two watcher for each row in this case.

The only way to remove watchers (all of them) is to create a custom directive that:

- hides the label and show the input on double click
- shows the label and hide the input when pressing enter

Example:

```
module.directive('myClick', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var span = element.find('span'),
          input = element.find('input');

      input.hide();

      span.on('dblclick', function() {
        if (span.is(':visible')) {
          span.hide();
          input.show();
          input.val(span.text());
        }
      });

      input.on('keypress', function(e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
          input.hide();
          span.show();
          span.text(input.val());
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Html:

```
...
<div ng-repeat="todo in vm.todos" my-click>
  <span>{{todo}}</span><input>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Hi. But this will allow multiple edits at the same time time

Comment: For this you could add a wrapper directive that expose an api to hide all the inputs when double clicking. Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/HQ6zUl

Comment: Thank you. This leads me to ask when should I use `ng-if` ( I know that it totally removes it from the dom) but still it uses watchers (right?) - But it costs and doesn't come for free. What would you do in my case?

Comment: The only difference between `ng-if` and `ng-show` is that the first one removes the element from the DOM while the second one hides it (in forms you may prefer to remove an input instead of hiding it). Both comes with the same cost: one watcher. Angular's two-way data binding is pretty amazing but also expensive, I try to avoid that with custom directives whenever it's possible, and yours would be one of those cases. However a watcher here and there is not *that* bad and helps you a lot in saving code.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I've changed the solution a bit according to your answer. but after doing that I thought to myself : " Hey i'm making this NG app into NG-JQUERY app - do I really want that?" Do you see what i mean ? Also - I don't care about a watcher here and there but as you can see as long as the todos items are growing  -- the watchers are growing also...

Comment: [Here is the edit](http://plnkr.co/edit/w78faYHxYcJvBGwyHi2W?p=preview) - I removed many directives like ng-if etc. Made it more like jQuery style. I don't know if it's better. ( watchers count did reduced) I'll be happy to hear from your expereince about the edit.

Comment: It's not bad to use jQuery: directives have been made for this reason. The important is that you keep them isolated: you should only manipulate the inner html of the directive without going out of scope (e.g. a 'myButton' directive that changes the background color doesn't make sense).
Also keep in mind:
- better a `ng` directive than a custom one with a $watch inside (it's still a watcher)
- event emitters like `ng-click` don't create watcher
- there is a bind once syntax that removes the watcher after the first binding: `ng-if=::condition`

Comment: ?? Does ng-if="expr" create a watch ????? I thought that only explicit watchers and {{}} create watchers .... So what about ngif ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97066/discussion-between-mario-lamacchia-and-royi-namir).